# phpunit testing not working on Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

I am new to using phpunit in Laravel for testing. When I tried and typed in phpunit in commandline, I got an 
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/845KL.png).

I even tried to to use ./vendor/bin/phpunit like most people suggested and it still doesn't work. Here are all the errors that I have gotten. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4dcl.png)

Comment: what is the exact laravel version you are using? Your phpunit seems to be outdated - you should try to update it. Also try running the following command from the root of your project `call ./vendor/bin/phpunit`

Answer (score 1):

You need first to run composer, after this you have to run phpunit using the convention of your OS, I saw you are in Windows, so you need to run vendor\bin\phpunit or you can use gitbash to emulate Unix system.

Comment: Wow I can't believe this, I was using the forward slash instead of the backward slash. No wonder I got the error 'vendor' is not an internal command. Thanks RafaelQm.